# How to prevent linux soft lockup/unresponsiveness in C without sleep

Tags: c, loops, freeze

How would be the correct way to prevent a soft lockup/unresponsiveness in a long running while loop in a C program?

(dmesg is reporting a soft lockup)

Pseudo code is like this:

```
while( worktodo ) {
  worktodo = doWork();
}
```

My code is of course way more complex, and also includes a printf statement which gets executed once a second to report progress, but the problem is, the program ceases to respond to ctrl+c at this point.

Things I've tried which do work (but I want an alternative):

- doing printf every loop iteration (don't know why, but the program becomes responsive again that way (???)) - wastes a lot of performance due to unneeded printf calls (each doWork() call does not take very long)
- using sleep/usleep/... - also seems like a waste of (processing-)time to me, as the whole program will already be running several hours at full speed

What I'm thinking about is some kind of process_waiting_events() function or the like, and normal signals seem to be working fine as I can use kill on a different shell to stop the program.

Additional background info: I'm using [GWAN](http://www.gwan.com) and my code is running inside the main.c "maintenance script", which seems to be running in the main thread as far as I can tell.

Thank you very much.

P.S.: Yes I did check all other threads I found regarding soft lockups, but they all seem to ask about *why* soft lockups occur, while I know the *why* and want to have a way of preventing them.

P.P.S.: Optimizing the program (making it run shorter) is not really a solution, as I'm processing a 29GB bz2 file which extracts to about 400GB xml, at the speed of about 10-40MB per second on a single thread, so even at max speed I would be bound by I/O and still have it running for several hours.

Comment: The work loop should be in a secondary thread, at the beginning of the loop, check a semaphore to see if the loop should be exited.  In main, you can create a signal handler to handle ctrl+c, which should set the semaphore and wait.  Main then would just be waiting for the worker loop to signal it has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the posed answer using threads might possibly be an option, it would in reality just shift the problem to a different thread. My solution after all was using

```
sleep(0)
```

Also tested sched_yield / pthread_yield, both of which didn't really help. Unfortunately I've been unable to find a good resource which documents sleep(0) in linux, but for windows the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that using a value of 0 lets the thread yield it's remaining part of the current cpu slice.

It turns out that sleep(0) is most probably relying on what is called *timer slack* in linux - an article about this can be found here: http://lwn.net/Articles/463357/

Another possibility is using `nanosleep(&(struct timespec){0}, NULL)` which seems to not necessarily rely on *timer slack* - [linux man pages for nanosleep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) state that if the requested interval is below clock granularity, it will be rounded up to clock granularity, which on linux depends on CLOCK_MONOTONIC according to the man pages. Thus, a value of 0 nanoseconds is perfectly valid and should always work, as clock granularity can never be 0.

Hope this helps someone else as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is not really a soft lock up, it is a process is busy doing something.

How about this pseudo code:

```
void workerThread()
{
    while(workToDo)
    {
       if(threadSignalled)
          break;

      workToDo = DoWork()
    }
}

void sighandler()
{
   signal worker thread to finish
   waitForWorkerThreadFinished;
 }

void main()
{
    InstallSignalHandler;
    CreateSemaphore
    StartThread;
    waitForWorkerThreadFinished;
}
```

Comment: I _do_ get soft lockup messages in dmesg, which really is a problem, as the program will be executed frequently, and spamming the sys log isn't really that great. For the worker thread suggestion: Wouldn't I have the same soft lockup problem in that case in the worker thread (syslog messages)?

Comment: Soft lockup in dmesg suggests a kernel/driver problem, not a user-mode  issue.

Comment: dmesg states the program as the source of the soft lockup - can it still be a kernel/driver problem in that case? On a sidenote, I'm using gwan app server ( http://www.gwan.com/ ) and don't have full control over the program, but my "c maintenance script main.c" seems to be running in the main thread as far as I can tell.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly a timing issue. Using a signalling mechanism should remove the problem.

The use of printf solves the problem because printf accesses the console which is an expensive and time consuming process which in your case gives enough time for the worker to complete its work.

Comment: While I wasn't the one downvoting, your answer neither helps, nor does it apply (I only have one thread, no "worker" there). Also, the reason printf most probably works as I know now is due to it being/resulting in a sycall, and thus a context switch. Maybe you wanted to answer to a different question?